# Why ListView row's background resource change when I using?

Tags: android, listview, background

I am developing android application about personal budget. When I list transactions, I am using `ListView`. On `ListView` I show income, expense and transfer transactions that all have different background resource. But when I scroll down to the listview and come up again the background image changes. Can someone tell me the reason why its happening so?

This is my code example;

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transactionline, null);

    transaction.setType(Integer.parseInt(item.get("Type")));

    if(transaction.getType()==1){
        anaalan.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.greenbutton);
    }else if(transaction.getType()==3)
    {
        anaalan.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.buttonstyle);
    }

    return vi;
}
```

Comment: @kirankumar don't paste chunks of code into comments. If this should be an answer, make it one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
if (position % 2 == 1)
   { 
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);    
   }
 else
   { 
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
   }
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

Comment: I didnt use this solution but I understand that this problem cause may be about if else structure. I added my code else { other button resource } and problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here's the answer for your problem.

as we all know ListView reuses converView and shows new values in reused view. so whenever you scroll ListView up or down listItems which are disappeared from the screen get reused with the new listItems which just comes on screen.

so, when you add background color to some of listItem with somthing like green, then when it disappear from screen and get reused for new listItem it already has it's background color as green so new item also get that green colored background and as fast you scroll list up and down eventually all the items become green.

and one more thing always give your ListView fixed height like fill_Parent or something like 500dp because when getView() started to draw items it will calculate size of first three list items and then calculate size for rest of the items with the height of listview.

so what i do in such situation is, i gives every view a transparent color by default and after that apply my logic to make it to some other color.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder;
        if (convertView == null){
            holder = new Holder();
            convertView =   View.inflate(context, R.layout.item, null);
            holder.txtID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.txtName  =   (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        if (Integer.parseInt( setter.get(position).getId() ) % 3 == 0  ){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

        if (Integer.parseInt( setter.get(position).getId() ) % 2 == 0 ){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }

        holder.txtID.setText(setter.get(position).getId());
        holder.txtName.setText(setter.get(position).getName());


        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Nasser for your answer. I understand this structure how to work.